# ModuleNotFoundError: 'matplotlib_inline'

Tags: azure, tensorflow, matplotlib, object-detection-api

I try to run an object detector on a compute instance on Azure ML. I'm using the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), and have installed Tensorflow along with CUDA and CUDNN according to [tensorflow.org/install/gpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#install_cuda_with_apt).

When running the following command:

```
python Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=2000
```

I get the following error:

```
2021-08-09 12:07:09.368060: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 35, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 25, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_tools
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pycocotools import coco
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycocotools/coco.py", line 49, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2282, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 221, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib_inline'
```

- The VM in Azure is running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
- I have installed both `matplotlib` and `matplotlib-inline` via pip and imported successfully
- The code is run in VS Code which is connected to the compute instance in Azure.
- CUDA version 11.0
- Python version 3.8.1

I haven't found any similar issues online and would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: A couple hints/questions: 1) You say you're running Python version **3.8.1** while the error message is from python **3.6**. So perhaps maybe you didn't end up installing matplotlib on that version? i.e. maybe your local version of python and the version on the remote VM is different? 2) The error is being thrown from the cocotools library, which must be imported by the object detection API, so try to simply import the cocotools library on the VM: `from pycocotools import coco`

Comment: It seems like the code switches between running python 3.6 and 3.8 somehow: I now have in VSCode configured the kernel to be running python 3.6 (azureml_py36) as well as python 3.6 interpreter. When e.g. running `import wget` i get a `ModuleNotFoundError`, but when i try to `pip install wget` in the VSCode terminal i get the following message `Requirement already satisfied: wget in /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.2)`. Now it looks in python 3.8 instead of 3.6 How can this be?

Comment: If you are explicitly using the matplotlib inline, note that it is ideal to use it in Jupyter notebook using % like `%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` .

Answer (score 0):

changing backend works for me like:

```
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```